# Set aside a specific list of colors in a linear color scale

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way to create a color scale and also keep aside a color, let's say green, to be used later on for another task?

If we can do this with one of the scale.category arrays, that is even much better.

Thanks for the answers in advance (if any).

Cheers,
Arman

Comment: You could simply use a color that's not in the scale.

Comment: I can't since I need specific colors that are not similar, and since the colors are being generated dynamically, it almost always happens that a shade of the colors I need (green as an example) is among the generated colors.

Comment: So just remove the colour you want before passing it to the scale.

Comment: That is the problem.
You can give the colors as the range of the scale, but you cannot say I want everything but this color.

Comment: Of course you can, just don't pass the colour you want to keep aside to the scale.

Comment: Correct.You have to give as input an array of colors, and not include the color you want to keep. In this case, it is highly likely that a very close solor to the set-aside color gets generated.

And again my question is "how to say I want green to not be used", not "how to say I want everything, while I am not including green intentionally".

Comment: 1) Create the colour scale. 2) Get the range (i.e. the colours) of that scale. 3) Reset the range of the scale as the one you got earlier minus the colour you want to keep aside.